# Replace word and remove extra spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm using the following code to replace ampersands with "and"s. The problem I have is when I have multiple ampersands next to each other I end up with two spaces between the "and"s ("-and--and-" instead of "-and-and-"). Is there a way I can combine the bottom two regex replaces into a single one while only removing duplicate spacing between ampersands?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var replacedWord = Regex.Replace("&&", @"\s*&\s*", " and ");
        var withoutSpaces = Regex.Replace(replacedWord, @"\s+and\s+", " and ");
        Console.WriteLine(withoutSpaces);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `Regex` for something `String.Replace("&","and")` could accomplish as well?

Comment: As a quick solution you can use string method `Trim()`

Comment: \s*&\s* will remove duplicate spaces around & ("--&-" will become "-and-")

Comment: It will also add spaces if & is within a word ("ab&c" will become "ab-and-c")

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks that mostly works however is it possible to make the ands have a space after it? For example "a&b" becomes "a-and-b". In the one you provided it becomes "a-andb".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `String` extension method for repeating,

```
public static string Repeat(this string s, int n) => new StringBuilder(s.Length * n).Insert(0, s, n).ToString();
```

You can use the lambda (delegate) version of `Regex.Replace`:

```
var withoutSpaces = Regex.Replace("a&&b", @"(\s*&\s*)+", m => " "+"and ".Repeat(m.Groups[1].Captures.Count));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "some&very&&longa&&&string";
string pattern = "&";
string x = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m =>(input[m.Index-1] == '&' ? "": "-") + "and-");
```